# Can't connect Windows 10 client to AWS Aurora MySQL database after major version upgrade 2 - 3

Tags: database-connection, amazon-aurora, windows-10-desktop

My system: Windows 11, Windows 10, and Ubuntu 22.04 clients run a Java application that accesses an AWS Aurora MySQL database.

What changed: Aurora was version 2.11.2 supporting MySQL 5.7.
I upgraded it, to version 3.05.2 supporting MySQL 8. That involved also upgrading its EC2 instance from t2.small to t4g.medium.

The problem: After the upgrade, the Windows 10 clients timeout when trying to connect to the database. The Windows 11 and Ubuntu clients can still access it as normal.

Java reports this:
`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`
Followed by a bunch of these:
`The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

Telnet reports this:
`C:\Users\array>telnet production.<aws_account>.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306 Connecting To production.<aws_account>.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com... Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed`

I tried rebooting Aurora. No change.

I restored an SQLdump of the Aurora database to an AWS RDS MySQL Community database, version 8.0.35.
Seems *all* clients can access that.

So this problem seems particular to Windows 10 clients and Aurora 3.
There's a lot of Q&As about problems connecting to Aurora databases, but I can't find any specific to Windows 10.